# Rails: Overwrite Form Builder's button method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

when I use the Form Builder in form_for to generate a button (with f.button) it generates a button with the title " ". What I want to do is add a prefix to this title: "MyPrefix  ".
So basically all I need to do is overwrite the button method (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/488699166c3558963fa82d4689a35f8c3fd93f47/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1402). But how do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? 
`f.button "", :title => "MyPrefix"`
Or do you want to have `f.button` generate <button title="MyPrefix " ... />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a [Custom Form Builder](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) (search for "customized form builders" on that page).

The code would be something roughly like the following (you'll have to decide where exactly the prefix should go):

```
class PrefixedFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
   def button(value=nil)
      super(value, :title => 'MyPrefix')
   end
end
```

with a custom helper in ApplicationHelper:

```
def prefixed_form_for(record, *args, &block)
   options = args.extract_options!
   options.merge!(:builder => PrefixedFormBuilder)
   form_for(record, *(args + [options]), &block)
end
```

and then using:

```
prefixed_form_for(@model) do |f|
```

in your views.

Comment: Sounds promising. But where would I have to put that code and how to make sure that my custom code is used and not the standard code?

Comment: prefixed_form_for... did not work for me; but form_for @model, :builder => PrefixedFormBuilder does work!
So Thanks for the help!

Comment: ...and if you add this to your environment.rb:
ActionView::Base.default_form_builder = PrefixedFormBuilder
..then you do not need to change anything in your form!

Comment: Sounds like a good solution in your case. I forgot that you have to define the helper for `prefixed_form_for`, I'll add the code for that in case anyone comes across the answer later.